# Cannot generate Mandelbrot matrix to save it to file in c++ threads

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm starting with my c++ threads and don't understand some basic stuff. That's Mandelbrot example, it generates fractal image.
It's not my code, I just did some changes (here's original: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set#PPM_non_interactive)

I have this function which generates matrix with colors to save to file:

```
vector<unsigned char *> drawMandelbrot()
{
   /* screen ( integer) coordinate */
   int iX, iY;

   double Cx, Cy;
   const double CxMin = -2.5;
   const double CxMax = 1.5;
   const double CyMin = -2.0;
   const double CyMax = 2.0;
   double PixelWidth = (CxMax - CxMin) / iXmax;
   double PixelHeight = (CyMax - CyMin) / iYmax;

   int Index = 0;

   const int IterationMax = 200;
   unsigned char color[3];
   vector<unsigned char *> rows(MaxIndex);
   double Zx, Zy;
   double Zx2, Zy2;
   int Iteration;
   const double EscapeRadius = 2;
   double ER2 = EscapeRadius * EscapeRadius;

   for (iY = 0; iY < iYmax; iY++)
   {
      Cy = CyMin + iY * PixelHeight;
      if (fabs(Cy) < PixelHeight / 2)
         Cy = 0.0; /* Main antenna */
      for (iX = 0; iX < iXmax; iX++)
      {
         Cx = CxMin + iX * PixelWidth;
         /* initial value of orbit = critical point Z= 0 */
         Zx = 0.0;
         Zy = 0.0;
         Zx2 = Zx * Zx;
         Zy2 = Zy * Zy;
         /* */
         for (Iteration = 0; Iteration < IterationMax && ((Zx2 + Zy2) < ER2); Iteration++)
         {
            Zy = 2 * Zx * Zy + Cy;
            Zx = Zx2 - Zy2 + Cx;
            Zx2 = Zx * Zx;
            Zy2 = Zy * Zy;
         };
         /* compute  pixel color (24 bit = 3 bytes) */
         if (Iteration == IterationMax)
         { /*  interior of Mandelbrot set = black */
            color[0] = 0;
            color[1] = 0;
            color[2] = 0;
         }
         else
         {                  /* exterior of Mandelbrot set = white */
            color[0] = 255; /* Red*/
            color[1] = 255; /* Green */
            color[2] = 255; /* Blue */
         };

         rows[Index] = color;
         Index++;
      }
   }
   return rows;
}
```

Here is function to save it to file:

```
void saveToFile(vector<unsigned char *> matrix, char *filename)
{
   char *comment = (char *)"# "; /* comment should start with # */
   FILE *file;
   file = fopen(filename, "wb"); /* b -  binary mode */
   fprintf(file, "P6\n %s\n %d\n %d\n %d\n", comment, iXmax, iYmax, MaxColorComponentValue);

   for (int Index = 0; Index < MaxIndex; Index++)
   {
      fwrite(matrix[Index], 1, 3, file);
   }

   fclose(file);
}
```

Some global values and main loop:

```
const int iXmax = 1000;
const int iYmax = 1000;
const int MaxColorComponentValue = 255;
int const MaxIndex = (iXmax * iYmax) - 1;

int main()
{
   clock_t start = clock();
   vector<unsigned char *> image = drawMandelbrot();
   clock_t stop = clock();
   cout << (double(stop - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << " seconds\n";

   char *filename = (char *)"new2.ppm";
   saveToFile(image,filename);
   return 0;
}
```

Problem is that generateMandelbrot() returns matrix like this:
[image matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLVUU.png)

but it should be vector of elements looks like this which is actually color value:
[color char](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GGMD.png)

I know the problems is with color and image values types, but have any idea how it should look like.
Thanks!

Comment: Please don't tag C++ code with C. In general, read the descriptions of tags before applying them. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, reduce your code to a [mcve]. In particular, the threading seems to be a distraction only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
     rows[Index] = color;
```

Is assigning the `unsigned char *` in your `vector` to the same array every time!

In other words it's like if I sell you ten cars and deliver the keys but they are all identical keys to the same car.  Wouldn't you be upset?

Change your variables to use `std::array`:

```
using Color = std::array<unsigned char, 3>;
Color color;
vector<Color> rows(MaxIndex);
```

Now you have a vector of triples (Colors), instead of a vector of pointers that all point at the same triple.

Comment: Omg so obvious! Thanks, i'm serious beginner.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Once you're satisfied with an answer please click the green checkmark on its left side to "accept" it.

Comment: you can make the keys in fancy different colors, then I'd be fine with it. I mean who needs 10 cars?!